# How to make multiple changes to a line if occurence of a word in a line using awk?

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks like this with no header and has 2059 lines and 6 columns:
An RQ... ID exists in column 2 of the file only in some lines (bold). E.g in the example below, it exists in the lines beginning with 141, 147 and 148.

```
136     471254  0       0       2       -0.487238289
137     472084  0       0       2       -0.324059074
138     471040  0       0       2       -0.199028334
139     472755  0       0       2       -9
140     471309  0       0       2       -9
141     **RQ00245-7**       0       0       2       -0.532578612
142     471311  0       0       2       2.593358921
143     472898  0       0       2       -0.525585159
144     471327  0       0       2       -9
145     471097  0       0       2       -0.20795088
146     472930  0       0       2       -9
147     **RQ00255-5**       0       0       2       -0.215851064
148    **RQ002657-9**       0       0       2       -0.9847894030
```

I want to change every line only if there is an occurrence of the word that begins with RQ in column 2. I want to do two things if RQ... exists in column 2 in a line:

1. I would like to repeat this specific RQ ID in column 1 of the same line.
2. I would also like to change the value in column 6 of the same line to a '-9' in all cases.  Therefore, changes are only implemented in lines where RQ... exists in the second column. Therefore the file should look like this:

```
136     471254  0       0       2       -0.487238289
137     472084  0       0       2       -0.324059074
138     471040  0       0       2       -0.199028334
139     472755  0       0       2       -9
140     471309  0       0       2       -9
RQ00245-7      RQ00245-7       0       0       2       -9
142     471311  0       0       2       2.593358921
143     472898  0       0       2       -0.525585159
144     471327  0       0       2       -9
145     471097  0       0       2       -0.20795088
146     472930  0       0       2       -9
RQ00255-5    RQ00255-5       0       0       2       -9
RQ002657-9    RQ002657-9       0       0       2       -9
```

---

I am new to awk but I am assuming it will start something like this (with an if statement saying if column `2` begins with `RQ` then change column `6` to `-9` and change column `1` identical to column `2`:

```
awk '{ if '$2~/^RQ/' ) $6="-9", $2 = $1;}'
```

Comment: Can you please show your attempt in question

Comment: I am new to awk but I am assuming it will start something like this (with an if statement saying if column 2 begins with RQ then change column 6 to -9 and change column 1 identical to column 2:  '{ if  '$2~/^RQ/'  ) $6="-9", $2 = $1;}'

Comment: [edit] your question to show your attempt (and all other relevant information), don't add it as comments where it can't be formatted and could be missed.

Comment: @HKJ3: As suggested by Ed please add this code in your question be clicking [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69974783/edit) link below your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk '$2 ~ /^RQ/ {$1 = $2; $NF = -9} 1' file | column -t

136         471254      0  0  2  -0.487238289
137         472084      0  0  2  -0.324059074
138         471040      0  0  2  -0.199028334
139         472755      0  0  2  -9
140         471309      0  0  2  -9
RQ00245-7   RQ00245-7   0  0  2  -9
142         471311      0  0  2  2.593358921
143         472898      0  0  2  -0.525585159
144         471327      0  0  2  -9
145         471097      0  0  2  -0.20795088
146         472930      0  0  2  -9
RQ00255-5   RQ00255-5   0  0  2  -9
RQ002657-9  RQ002657-9  0  0  2  -9
```

**Details:**

- `$2 ~ /^RQ/` checks if 2nd column starts with `RQ`
- `$1 = $2; $NF = -9`: Sets 1st field value as 2nd field and sets last field to `-9`
- `column -t` has been used for tabular output